# How do I make the layouts in rows?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I am trying to make the layout stabilized and fixed. When I resized the window, it gives me just one line instead of an actual row layout. How do I make the layout neat?

Here is my code:

```
class BookstoreFrame extends JFrame
{
   JButton btnSubmit;
   JTextField txtISBN, txtTitle, txtAuthor, txtPrice;
   JLabel lblISBN, lblTitle, lblAuthor, lblPrice;
   int count = 0;

   public BookstoreFrame(String title)
   {
      FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 20);
      setLayout(layout);

      lblISBN = new JLabel("ISBN: ");
      txtISBN = new JTextField(10);
      lblTitle = new JLabel("Book Title: ");
      txtTitle = new JTextField(10);
      lblAuthor = new JLabel("Author: ");
      txtAuthor = new JTextField(10);
      lblPrice = new JLabel("Price: ");
      txtPrice = new JTextField(10);

      btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
      add(lblISBN);
      add(txtISBN);
      add(lblTitle);
      add(txtTitle);
      add(lblAuthor);
      add(txtAuthor);
      add(lblPrice);
      add(txtPrice);
      add(btnSubmit);
      btnSubmit.addActionListener(new seeTextBookInfo());
   }
}
```

Comment: Sound like you want `GridLayout`

Answer (score 0):

You are using FlowLayout, it adds the components in one direction until there is no more space and then creates a new line.

You could use BoxLayout, to add the elements from left to right: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html

```
BoxLayout layout = BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make the layout neat?

We have no idea what "neat" means to you?

Typically you would have label/text field pairs on a single row, then maybe the button on its own row.

I would suggest you might want to use the `GridBagLayout` as it allows you to have flexible row and column grids for your components.

The basic code might be something like:

```
setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
add(lblISBN, gbc);

gbc.gridx = 1;
add(txtISBN, gbc);

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 1;
add(lblTitle);

gbc.gridx = 1;
add(txtTitle);

... // add other components here

gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = ?;
gbc.gridwidth = 2;
gbc.anchor = ???
add(btnSubmit);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information and examples to get you started.